# Оптимизация RecyclerView с обложками из альбомов

Tags: android, recyclerview, glide

Есть  `RecyclerView`  с информацией об альбомах. При прокрутке есть фризы, из-за подгрузки обложек, которые берутся из mp3. Каким образом я могу оптимизировать его ?

Параметры RecyclerView

```
myRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(300); 
myRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlbumViewHolder holder, int position) {
           holder.tv_album_title.setText(mAlbumList.get(position).getAlbum());
           uri = Uri.parse(mAlbumList.get(position).getData());
           retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString());
           art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
           if (art != null) {
               Glide.with(mContext)
                       .asBitmap()
                       .load(art)
                       .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
                       .override(100, 100)
                       .placeholder(R.drawable.default_cover)
                       .into(holder.album_cover_albumFragment);
           } else {
               Glide.with(mContext)
                       .asBitmap()
                       .load(R.drawable.default_cover)
                       .override(100, 100)
                       .into(holder.album_cover_albumFragment);
           }
   }
```

album_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="4dp">


   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/album_cover_albumFragment"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
       android:layout_height="45dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/album_title_albumFragment"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textSize="16sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Скорее всего вот эти строки тормозят uri = Uri.parse(mAlbumList.get(position).getData());
           retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString());
           art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();

Comment: Надо их вынести в отдельный поток тем или иным способом. Простого решения в пару строк тут не будет, надо будет написать достаточно много относительно сложного кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел на ютубе решение https://youtu.be/J55pR7EvVUQ. Всё хорошо работает, но пришлось доработать, так как у меня при нажатии открывается другая `activity`.

Перестал работать `interface`, который отвечал за слушателя в `RecyclerView`, переделал таким образом:

Класс слушателя

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
}
```

Объявляем слушателя

```
myRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), myRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //Do what you need after click
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //Do what you need after long click
                    }
                })
        );
```

При возврате к `RecyclerView` приложение вылетало, фиксил так https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822747/17839298 :

```
public class WrapContentLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
        public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
            super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
            try {
                super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Потом применяем к `RecyclerView`

```
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

Дальше заметил, что моргает первый элемент `RecyclerView`, на секунду подгружалась другая обложка, помог данный код:

```
myRecyclerView.swapAdapter(albumsAdapter, false);
```